# Delphi Downloading file using WebBrowser/IdHttp from form submit

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, idhttp

I need to download a file from a webpage.  I tried using `TWebBrowser` and `TIdHTTP` in Delphi, but I am not succeeding.

I could not find the link to the file.  When I click an HMTL button to download, a form submission is executed, and a download window appears immediately. I tried copying the link that appears in the file details in the download window, but the link does not work if I just paste it in the browser.

Link from file on download window:

https://aplicacao3.tst.jus.br/visualizacaoAutos/VisualizarPecas.pub?VisualizarTodos=1

Code from download button:

```
<input name="visualizarTodos" value="Visualizar processo em um único PDF de 61,49 MB" onclick="javascript:submete();" id="botaoVisualizarTodos" class="botao" title="Visualizar Todas as peças listadas abaixo em um único PDF. Tamanho estimado: 61,49 MB. (Alt + F10)" type="button">
```

Code from submete();

```js
function submete(){
    if(indArquivoParaExportacaoGrandeDemais()) {
        mostraMensagemBotaoIndisponivelPorContaDoTamanho();
    } else {
        document.forms[0].target='_blank'
        temp = document.forms[0].action;
        document.forms[0].action = document.forms[0].action+ "?visualizarTodos=1";
        document.forms[0].submit();
        document.forms[0].action = temp;
        document.forms[0].target='_self'
    }   
}
```

Is there any way to download the file in this case?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the HTML page that provides this download button? Is it publically accessible, or do you have to login to reach it? What does the complete HTML `<form>` look like? Pasting the download link in the browser address bar does not work because the server is expecting the URL to be requested by a `POST` request, not a `GET` request. You can simulate an HTML form submission in `TIdHTTP` using its `Post()` method with a `TStrings` or `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` object for the form values, depending on the value of the `enctype` attribute of the `<form>`.

Comment: Debug this with chrome dev tools or similar. Trace the requests.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It requires login and password. The URL of HTML page is https://aplicacao3.tst.jus.br/visualizacaoAutos/VisualizarPecas.do?load=1&anoProcInt=2013&numProcInt=1282&origem=consultarProcesso, the Form HTML is `<form name="VisualizarPecasForm" method="post" action="/visualizacaoAutos/VisualizarPecas.pub">`

Comment: That is not the complete `<form>`. What `<input>` elements does it have? You will have to `POST` all non-empty `<input>` values (using a `TStrings` object, since `enctype` is omitted). Also, since login is involved, chances are cookies are being used to track login state. So make sure you `Get()` the HTML page first to grab any needed cookies before then `Post()`'ing the page's form data. Like David said, use your browser's built-in developer tools to see how the file is being requested.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my bad! The complete Form HTML is `<form name="VisualizarPecasForm" method="post" action="/visualizacaoAutos/VisualizarPecas.pub">
     <input name="anoProcInt" value="2013" type="hidden">
 <input name="numProcInt" value="1282" type="hidden">
 <input name="origem" value="consultarProcesso" type="hidden">
 <input name="processoLiberadoParaEdicaoUsuario" value="" type="hidden">
 <input name="liberadaAlteracaoOrdenacao" value="" type="hidden">
`

Comment: Then you need something like this: `Stream := TFileStream.Create('local filename', fmCreate); Params := TStringList.Create; Params.Add('anoProcInt=2013'); Params.Add('numProcInt=1282'); Params.Add('origem=consultarProcesso'); Params.Add('processoLiberadoParaEdicaoUsuario=...'); Params.Add('liberadaAlteracaoOrdenacao=...'); IdHttp.Post('https://aplicacao3.tst.jus.br/visualizacaoAutos/VisualizarPecas.pub?visualizarTodos=1', Params, Stream); Params.Free; Stream.Free;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @RemyLebeau, make that as answer, I'd vote for it ;)